# Can I ask questions about Linux Mint here?

Tags: discussion

**First of all, I am not an expert at computer, and I am totally new to Linux.**

Hello there. As I said, I am new to Linux; A few days ago I installed Linux Mint in my Exo PC.

But I am having some issues;

This website was really useful for resolving issues with Linux Mint, even that it is a website related to Ubuntu

So, I wanted to ask; Can I ask questions about resolving issues in Linux Mint here?

I think that my issue (A screen recording issue) could be resolved just as if it was an Ubuntu OS.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but this is not about Ubuntu and therefore off topic since other distributions mostly have different approaches about how to handle things we cant support that, so you might be better off asking your question on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Please do not cross-post, flag your answer instead for moderator attention if you wish it to be migrated there. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Questions about other Linux distributions that are not supported by Canonical are off topic at Ask Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on [Unix & Linux Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).